# Github only half of the total files is being push

Tags: github, terminal

I've put into a big trouble. Yesterday night I've commit my code to the github, but unfortunately only few files have committed , not the all which I've updated. After that client has committed his own changes into the half committed source, in the morning. After an hour I pull the code from github which client has committed & I found my yesterday's changes are lost & only half of the code has committed. Now do guide me what should I do? It is not possible to integrate my code into client's file, because I've edited so much & neither I can overwrite my files with client's he has also done his changes. What to do? Please guide me to the proper way. It's an emergency.

I've used following code to push my code

- git add -a
- git commit -m "comment"
- git push origin master

---

Any help will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `git commit -a` your untracked files (the files you've created which git does not know yet) are not added to your commit. If you wanted to add all files changed/added you should have used `git add .` before commiting. Could this be the problem?

P.S. I don't understand why you would use `git commit -m` there. Usually you would use this last after using `git add filename`. `git commit -a` directly adds all tracked and modified files to a commit and lets you enter the commit message.

Comment: yes, I do agree with you, but earlier I have added my changes using this command only, & all files got successfully updates. I face this kinda problem today only & that is for the first time.

Comment: Again I do agree with your edited answer, but it shows 26 of files are updated out of 32,then how it could be possible ??

Comment: Then I am afraid it gets out of my reach. We're going to wait for someone more proficient to solve it :(